# How do I create a drop down list dependant on previous drop down and final choice displays text box

Tags: javascript

How do I create a drop down list dependant on previous drop down and final choice displays text box?

E.G. 1st drop down has a choice of 1, 2 & 3. 2nd list had a choice of A,B,C if I chose 1 from previous, D, E, F if I chose 2, or X,Y, Z if I chose 3.  Then if I chose any letter a text box displays with a message, (a different message for each letter choice)?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify how your output looks like?

Comment: On a HTML page, displaying 1 drop down, then a 2nd after making selection, then displaying a message. So in the end you'll see 2 drop downs and a text box.

Comment: What does the text box display?

Comment: Any text message. I want it to display in a text box and not as an alert.

Comment: This looks great.... almost what I was after, but instead of the value of 2nd option appearing in text box, how would I make a message appear. For example. I choose option 1, but the I have the option of choosing either A, B or C separately, and then, when, lets say I choose A, a message appears saying'Red'. If I were to choose B, a different message appears, e.g. 'Green', and for C, maybe a message 'Yellow' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways in pure javascript. Look into this sample implementation for some guidance to proceed further.

1) Create necessary html markup with two select and one input.
2) Handle change event on first select.
3) In `change` event handler, set the selected index same as that of first and populate input control.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');
var third = document.getElementById('third');
first.addEventListener('change', handleChangeEvent);

function handleChangeEvent() {
 var index = this.selectedIndex;
 second.selectedIndex = index;
 var inputValue = second.options[index].value;
 if(inputValue == 'A,B,C') {
    third.value = 'Red';
 } else if (inputValue == 'D,E,F') {
    third.value = 'Blue';
 } else {
    third.value = 'Green';
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="first">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value="A,B,C">A,B,C</option>
<option value="D,E,F">D,E,F</option>
<option value="X,Y,Z">X,Y,Z</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="third" />
```

Comment: This looks great.... almost what I was after, but instead of the value of 2nd option appearing in text box, how would I make a message appear. For example. I choose option 1, but the I have the option of choosing either A, B or C separately, and then, when, lets say I choose A, a message appears saying'Red'. If I were to choose B, a different message appears, e.g. 'Green', and for C, maybe a message 'Yellow' ??

Comment: @StevieM You can't choose 'A', 'B' or 'C' individually. If you want then your options will have to be individually 'A', 'B' or 'C' NOT `A,B,C`.

Comment: Sorry. I really appreciate your help, and I'm sorry I didn't explain myself properly!! I can work out the options from the drop downs, but can you help with the final stage? A different message displayed in the text box for each different choice chosen from the 2nd drop down.

Comment: @StevieM You have `second.options[index].value`. Use if/else if/else to write different values into the input control. Say, if(value == 'A,B,C') third.value = 'Red'.

Comment: @StevieM See my edited code and run that. That should give you an idea!

Comment: You've been so kind and helpful. Thanks so much for putting up with my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Several different ways come to mind: 
(I will explain using Bootstrap examples, other frameworks can be used or you can write a custom HTML/CSS/JS for yourself)

**Multiple Navigations:**
You select a tab in the 1st row then another row of selection appears below depending on what you selected in the top row. Repeat once more for the 3rd row.

see [Bootstrap Navigation tabs/pills](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

**Multiple dropdowns side by side left to right:**
You select 1st then when the user picks the value second one appears containing only options for that value and same goes for 3rd..

[Bootstrap dropdowns with or without nesting](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

**Multiple accordions:**
You have 3 levels of accordion nested in each other. As user picks one it expands revealing further options only available for that previous choice.

[Bootstrap collapsable and accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

**Dropdown with an accordion with submenus:**
Elegant mix of 2 beforementioned, dropdown contains 2 levels of an accordion for every item. you need to redo the dropdown that it only closes when an item in 2nd level in accordion is selected

**Nested dropdowns to left:**
[nested dropdowns example](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)

As for structuring the data I would go for nested objects (JSON like), you nest the 3rd selection into categories made of 2nd selection then altogather in 1st selection.